# Rails 4 x premailer x SASS: import stylesheet in mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, actionmailer, premailer

In my Rails 4 app, I use mailers to send out emails to users.

These mailers are working fine.

Now, I would like to style them, so I installed the [premailer-rails](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails) gem (and the [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem).

I restarted my server.

Then, I created a specific stylesheet for mailers: `public/assets/mailers.scss`

I my mailer view, I added:

```
<head>
  <% stylesheet_link_tag mailers "public/assets/mailers.scss" %>
</head>
```

However, when a user opens the email in his inbox, for instance Gmail, the style is not applied.

Is there a particular way to include stylesheets in mailer views in Rails with premailer when using SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `mailers` in you code snippet? If it is some helper that returns the name of the css file, then it's ok. See [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) in documentation what is expected by `stylesheet_link_tag` method.

Anyway, whatever it is, you are missing `=` sign, and you need it in order to render anything into you view:

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag mailers "public/assets/mailers.scss" %>
</head>
```

Answer (score -3):

No,there is no certain way to conclude stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask you if you have any idea about why my code is not working?